# Permanent redirect 301 with /?lang=de

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect a multilingual website to a new domain and will use an .htaccess file for it. I redirect all old pages to their respective new ones on the new domain.

OLD URLS

```
Englisch
    Main page: www.olddomain.com
    Sub pages: www.olddomain.com/bike-rental

Spanish
    Main: www.olddomain.com/?lang=es
    Sub pages: www.olddomain.com/bike-rental?lang=es

German
    Main: www.olddomain.com/?lang=de
    Sub pages: www.olddomain.com/bike-rental?lang=de
```

NEW URL's

```
Englisch
    Main page: www.new-domain.com
    Sub pages: www.new-domain.com/bike-rental

Spanish
    Main: www.new-domain.com/es
    Sub pages: www.new-domain.com/es/alquiler-de-bicis
German
    Main: www.new-domain.com/de
    Sub pages: www.new-domain.com/de/fahrradvermietung
```

I realized it does not work with a normal redirect in the .htaacces file 
    such as:

```
    Redirect 301 /?lang=de http://www.new-domain.com/de/
    Redirect 301 /bike-rental?lang=de http://www.new-domain.com/de/fahrradvermietung
```

Any ideas how to redirect those old URL's to the new ones?

Thanks

Comment: how are you achieving redirect? through code or webserver? mention more details

Answer (score 0):

Since php 5.3.0 This variable was added:

```
$locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
echo $locale; // returns "en_US"
$localeshort = substr($locale, -2);
echo $localeshort; // returns "US"
```

If you use this, you can make a redirect with something like:

```
Header("Location: index.php?lang=".$localeshort);
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry but I do not understand one word. Are you sure you read my question? I need to make 301 redirects from one domain to another....  how would a redirect from: 

    http://www.olddomain.com/bike-rental?lang=de 
    to 
    http://www.newdomain.com/de/fahrradvermietung

look like?

Answer (score 0):

OR use: [this tool](http://www.htaccesstools.com/redirection-by-language/) to create a redirect, repeat this until you have all languages. [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucDkp.png)

Comment: ...thanks but I need 301 redirects to a new domain... and this tool is certainly no redirecting urls to a new domain...

Answer (score 0):

See my previous message:
Since php this function was added:

```
$locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
echo $locale; // returns "en_US"
$localeshort = substr($locale, -2);
echo $localeshort; // returns "US"
```

Use in your .htacces

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [R=permanent,L]
```

Now it will be redirected to the page on the begin.
This is the only solution i know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bike-rental$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ /bike-rental?lang=%1 [L,R=301]
```

(Tested and added condition to avoid circular rewrite)

Comment: sorry but how would this link to a new domain I need to redirect: 

    www.old-domain.com/?lang=de  to www.new-domain.com/de

or sub-pages: 

    www.old-domain.com/bike-rental/?lang=de  to www.new-domain.com/de/fahrradvermietung

Comment: Always you can add in RewriteRule ^(.*)/ http//www.new-domain.com/bike-rental?lang=%1 [L,R=301] and for subpages you only need to change a little bit